# set of arrays to a new array

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a set of 2d arrays lets say a1[w][h],a2[w][h],a3[w][h],a4[w][h],a5[w][h] from a function.
Now i wan to pass these to another function so for this purpose i decide to create a 3d array which can hold these say A[w][h][5]. now the problem i face is filling up the array A with all the five different matrices. to fill it with one i can use for loops like

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
  for(j=0;j<w;j++)
  {
    for(k=0;k<h;k++)
    {
      A[j][k][i]=a1[j][k];
    }
  }
}
```

this fills up array A with a1 alone is there any way using for loops to do it in such a way that A can be filled with all 5 matrices.

Comment: Just put the above code in a function and call it five times (once for each input array).

Comment: You may wanna double check the indexing in that loop, because it looks off. (shouldn't `i` be indexing the *dominant* dimension rather than the most-inferior?).

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just pass them as 5 parameters to avoid copying the data around?

Comment: I don't see a need to copy anything, `Type (*tmp[])[w][h] = { &a1, &a2, &a3, &a4, &a5 };` If the function parameter is setup correctly you can reference all of them directly.

Comment: why downvote this it is a problem which can be face by beginners and would be helpful for them if not for the pros

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you are sure to get a set of 5 arrays, why not just doing :

```
A[0] = a1;
A[1] = a2;
...
A[4] = a5;
```

It would fill A with your arrays and would be a lot less greedy than 3 for loops.

Then you'd just have to pass A as your function argument.

Comment: Unfortunately the OP has the array index as the last index, not the first, so this won't work.

Comment: @Paul R Op said the purpose of his 3D array was to pass his arrays in another function. So no matter where the array index is ?

Comment: Nor would it work regardless. Native arrays are not allowable lvalues in C++.

Comment: @Paul R OP said : this actually works when A is assigned correctly. So I don't know, didn't try it myself, the only thing that matters is that op had is code working, and my answer is downvoted so other people might not use it or at least read the comments.

Comment: @Paul R this method works so i dont see the problem in accepting it. or atleast it serves my purpose and i am happy with the outcome so i donot see the problem.

Comment: @serpentor: well it doesn't work with the question *as stated* - but perhaps your question does not accurately reflect what you are trying to do?

Comment: @PaulR As said above in my question i have a function in which i end up generating 5 matrices.lets assume they represent a few different filters. I now want to take these filters so that they can be used on an image to perform wavelet transform. i have all the functions as seperate files and are not in one file.

Comment: Well your question is very poorly posed, and regardless of this I don't see how the above answer can work for your question (or any near variation of it), unless there is something you're not telling us?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, There's no easy way to do that. The essential reason is that a1..a5 array is in some corresponding continues memory, may not if you overlap the operator. Whereas the new 3d array should be at an another bulk of memory. Perhaps you can do the trick that malloc a memory lager enough to hold the and memory copy from the each 2d array. But the result of that is as Logar says before which your array index at the first not the last. So what you do in your post is a simplest way to do that in C++ language.

Answer (score 0):

You may try using pointer arrays, say, `(*a)[5] = {a1, a2, a3, a4, a5}`, and then use

```
A[j][k][i] = a[i][j*h+k]
```